# How to output image without background?

Tags: ios, swift, calayer

I have a canvasImageView and draw something on it.
And I want to output an image just contain image region.
My output function is `func saveBtnPressed(sender: UIButton)`.
Like following image, I want to output blue line region.
Have any idea to do this?
Thanks.

[image: output image]

```
class CanvasViewController: UIViewController {

    let canvasImageView: CanvasImageView = {
        let ui = CanvasImageView()
        ui.contentMode = .scaleAspectFit
        ui.layer.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        ui.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear
        ui.clipsToBounds = true
        ui.isMultipleTouchEnabled = false
        ui.isUserInteractionEnabled = true
        return ui
    }()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.title = "Color Yourself"

        let save = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .save, target: self, action: #selector(saveBtnPressed(sender:)))
        let redo = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .refresh, target: self, action: #selector(clearBtnPressed(sender:)))
        let back = UIBarButtonItem(barButtonSystemItem: .stop, target: self, action: #selector(cancelBtnPressed(sender:)))

        self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItems = [save, redo]
        self.navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem = back

        self.setupView()
    }

    fileprivate func setupView() {

        self.view.addSubview(canvasImageView)

        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            self.canvasImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.safeAreaLayoutGuide.topAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        } else {
            self.canvasImageView.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topLayoutGuide.bottomAnchor, constant: 0).isActive = true
        }

        self.canvasImageView.snp.makeConstraints { (make) in
            make.bottom.left.right.equalToSuperview()
        }

    }

    //MARK: BUTTON ACTION

    @objc func cancelBtnPressed(sender: UIBarButtonItem) {
        self.dismiss(animated: false, completion: nil)
    }

    @objc func clearBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) {
        canvasImageView.clearCanvas()
    }

    @objc func saveBtnPressed(sender: UIButton) {

        //Here is output image.
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.canvasImageView.layer.bounds.size, true, 0.0)
        self.canvasImageView.layer.render(in: UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!)
        let image = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext()
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext()

        if let img = image {
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(img, self,#selector(image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
        }

    }    
}
```

```
class CanvasImageView: UIImageView {

    var lineColor = UIColor.red
    var lineWidth: CGFloat = 10
    var path: UIBezierPath?
    var touchPoint: CGPoint!
    var startingPoint: CGPoint!

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {

        self.startingPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self)
    }

    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?) {
        self.touchPoint = touches.first?.location(in: self)
        self.path = UIBezierPath()
        path?.move(to: startingPoint)
        path?.addLine(to: touchPoint)
        self.startingPoint = touchPoint
        self.draw()
    }

    func draw() {
        let shapeLayer = CAShapeLayer()
        shapeLayer.path = path?.cgPath
        shapeLayer.strokeColor = lineColor.cgColor
        shapeLayer.lineWidth = lineWidth
        shapeLayer.fillColor = UIColor.clear.cgColor
        self.layer.addSublayer(shapeLayer)
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }

    func clearCanvas() {
        guard let drawPath = path else { return }
        drawPath.removeAllPoints()
        self.layer.sublayers = nil
        self.setNeedsDisplay()
    }
}
```

Comment: crop the area required

Comment: @AwaisMobeen Sorry, I want to ask how to get image area to crop?

Comment: func cropImage(image: UIImage, toRect: CGRect) -> UIImage? {
    // Cropping is available trhough CGGraphics
    let cgImage :CGImage! = image.cgImage
    let croppedCGImage: CGImage! = cgImage.cropping(to: toRect)

    return UIImage(cgImage: croppedCGImage)
} i am using this method to crop image

Comment: @AwaisMobeen sorry, I want to know how to get my image region. I don't know `toRect` I need to set what in your function.

Comment: in my scenario it was the rect of uiimage view because I need the same rect as of  image

Comment: you have to calculate the rect of the blue border area

Comment: @AwaisMobeen But I don't know how to calculate. Do you have any advice or answer to me.

Comment: the picture of mouse is in UIImageView that is the blue line area so the rect of imageview is your required rect

Comment: But my imageView is `scaleAspectFit`, so the image is smaller than original and my imageView region is full screen using autolayout.

Comment: in this case hard to find have to more R&D